# Getting 400 bad request error on google Talent Solutions api - symfony 4

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, symfony4, php-7.2, google-php-sdk

On implementation of google Talent solutions API, I am getting this error,

```
{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Creation request should not have name set.. Request ID for tracking: 07547685-f322-4e9a-b650-0505e3801a8a:APAb7ISK9V8RN0bV6KYUm3BBwoEpL9WDIg==",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Creation request should not have name set.. Request ID for tracking: 07547685-f322-4e9a-b650-0505e3801a8a:APAb7ISK9V8RN0bV6KYUm3BBwoEpL9WDIg==",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "badRequest"
}
],
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
}
```

I followed below steps for implementation:

- [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) client library
- Symfony Code :

  ```
  $client = new \Google_Client();
  $client->setAuthConfig("/pathformyclient file/client.json");
  $client->addScope(\Google_Service_CloudTalentSolution::JOBS);
  $client->setHttpClient(new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false]));
  $cloudTalentSolutionClient = new \Google_Service_CloudTalentSolution($client);
  $projectId = "my project ID";
  $parent = sprintf('projects/%s', $projectId);
  $company = new \Google_Service_CloudTalentSolution_Company();
  $company->setName("company name");
  $company->setDisplayName("company name");
  $company->setExternalId("1");
  $ci = new \Google_Service_CloudTalentSolution_CreateCompanyRequest();
  $ci->setCompany($company);
  $com = $cloudTalentSolutionClient->projects_companies->create($projectId,ci,array('parent' => $parent));
  dump($com);die
  ```

Kindly can you please help where I am missing or guide me in fixing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 400 means you have sent a Bad Request - duff data!

In your case, luckily, they tell you exactly what you did wrong - `Creation request should not have name set..`!

So, don't set the name, and hopefully next request won't be an HTTP 400!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

Comment: thanks!!!. I tried the same an hour ago. But didn't work.  Now after seeing your answer tried again and worked like a charm. :) thanks a lott!!!

Comment: glad i could help! Could you mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: Yes i did. Thanks :)